# Unable to install LDAP in node 12.7

Tags: node.js, ldap, npm, v8

I've upgraded my node version from 10 to 12.7 after which my LDAP module did not work.When i tried to install the latest LDAP version i got the below error

> npm install LDAP

```
> node-gyp rebuild



gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir      "/root/.node-gyp/0.12.7"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir   "/home/ubuntu/node_modules/LDAP/.node-gyp"
make: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/node_modules/LDAP/build'
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/LDAP/src/LDAP.o
 ../src/LDAP.cc:10:18: fatal error: ldap.h: No such file or directory
 compilation terminated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/LDAP/src/LDAP.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/node_modules/LDAP/build'
gyp ERR! build error
  gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-     gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit  (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-40-virtual
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/node_modules/LDAP
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-40-virtual
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "LDAP"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! LDAP@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the LDAP@1.2.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the LDAP package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls LDAP
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/npm-debug.log
```

and when i googled i came across the below thread

> https://github.com/jeremycx/node-LDAP/issues/70

which says that The v8 C API has changed dramatically in Node.js 0.12 compared to 0.10. Unfortunately, adaptation of the code would require epic refactoring of the C codebase..

Does that mean that the LDAP module does not support in the latest node or have i missed something .... kindly help

Comment: Thank you, tuanh118, your [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42007875/8201079) helped me a lot, you made my day!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get install libldap2-dev
```